# Set of 5 equations for 6 positive integer unknowns

Tags: systems-of-equations

The setup is that we have a total of 9 persons scattered in 6 groups. Each persons having a unknown number of pens and being part of two different groups. The repartition of the groups is like so :

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & \text{Group 1} & \text{Group 2}  & \text{Group 3}\\ \hline
\text{Group 4} & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 \\ \hline
\text{Group 5} & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 \\ \hline
\text{Group 6} & P_7 & P_8 & P_9 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

The total numbers of pens from each group are given :

$$
Group\ 1 : 204\\
Group\ 2 : 0\\
Group\ 3 : 135\\
Group\ 4 : 38\\
Group\ 5 : 93\\
Group\ 6 : 208\\
$$

**The objective is to know the number of pens owned by each person.**

I thought that it would obviously be a set of equations with a set of unknowns but the problem here is that we have 9 unkwnowns with only 6 equations.

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
P_1 + P_4 + P_7 &= 204\\
P_2 + P_5 + P_8 &= 0 \\
P_3 + P_6 + P_9 &= 135\\
P_1 + P_2 + P_3 &= 38\\
P_4 + P_5 + P_6 &= 93\\
P_7 + P_8 + P_9 &= 208\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Hopefully then, the second equation allows to reduce the number of unknowns to 6 but it also reduces the number of remaining equations to 5 :

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
P_1 + P_4 + P_7 &= 204\\
P_3 + P_6 + P_9 &= 135\\
P_1 + P_3 &= 38\\
P_4 + P_6 &= 93\\
P_7 + P_9 &= 208\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

To top it all, those equations are not linearily independant since the first equation can be retrieved as a combination of the last four.

I am leaded to think that there might be something that I missed which could allow me to reduce the number of unkwowns even more but I can't put my hands on it.

Could anyone here help me solve this?

Comment: There are obviously a lot of solutions that are determined by what you assign to $P_1$ and $P_4$. Do you have anything else?

Comment: No, that's about all, though. The original problem led me to think that there should be an unique solution but I don't see what more one can find about this.

Comment: You can narrow the number of solutions down somewhat, based on the constraint that all of the variables must be non-negative integers.  As an exercise, I explored the problem to determine if that constraint allowed the problem-solver to deduce that there was only one unique solution.  I could be mistaken.  However, I don't think that there is only one unique solution, even given the constraint re non-negative integers.

Comment: I suggest that you re-check the original wording of the problem.  If you omitted certain pertinent info, or made a typo in one of the equations, that could result in there being a unique solution.

Comment: @user2661923 That's exactly what I am thinking and I've been reading and re-reading the problem from top to bottom but I couldn't see what I missed. The problem is in French, I pasted it on imgur if you want to take a look https://imgur.com/a/m2ows9K

Comment: Is that all you have?

Comment: Yes that's all I have

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I think the solution would be something like what @ParclyTaxel suggested. The solution is not unique.